# What is the proper order of the code using the ADO.NET with parameter?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I write an ADO.NET connection and it working in retrieving data with a parameter but my problem after I retrieve one or 2 after you don't use the browser. It gets browser is not responding.

My Code:

```
 private readonly string _cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBMS"].ConnectionString;

        public List<string[]> FlatTypeById(long? id)
        {
            var list = new List<string[]>();
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_cs))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_Calc_By_Flat_Type_with_Total", cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LandID", id);

                cn.Open();
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        var rows = new string[rdr.FieldCount];

                        for (var i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                            rows[i] = rdr[i] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : rdr[i].ToString();
                        list.Add(rows);
                    }
                    rdr.NextResult();
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Any suggestion Guys? Please help? :(

Comment: suggest not mix ui with data logic

Comment: `can.Close()` won't be needed as the `cn` object is being created and scoped to the `using` block, it will be disposed at the end of the `using` block. Regarding unresponsive behavior, it might be due to the result set size. Please add info on the number of records and result sets (if any) being retrieved in the query so that it would help finding an optimal solution that suits your need.

Comment: @SivaramK you're the best Sir! thank you.

Comment: @PatrickPangilinan Did you find the root cause for your problem? _Please do vote the comment if it helped in resolving your problem_

Comment: @SiviramK Sir, I can't find the vote. How to do vote?